# How can I know if the general solution of this ODE is convex?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, convex-analysis

I would like to know if the set of solutions of the following third order linear ODE is convex.

$$y''' + y'' -2y' + y = e^x $$

Can I do that by solving it? Can I infer that from the fact that $y(x) = e^x$ is a particular solution and is a convex function?

Comment: From the the function on R.H.S. - $e^x$ - you can only derivate that the general solution has to have a term of the kind $Ae^x$. Therefore the general solution will have this convex part but I am not sure what exactly you are calling *convex*, could you explain this?

Comment: the question asked in my test asked if the set of solutions of the ODE is convex. Not sure if this clarifies.

Comment: For a subset $S$ of a linear space to be convex, $x, y\in S$ must imply $tx+(1-t)y\in S$ for all $t\in [0, 1]$. Try proving (or disproving) that for solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$, $ty_1+(1-t)y_2$ is also a solution for all $t$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: The characteristic equation of this third order ODE has two complex roots. Since complex roots lead to cosine and sine functions I am not sure if the whole set can be said to be convex. (By the way, the roots are $r_1=-2.1478990457,r_{2,3}=0.573949517852\pm 0.368989407482i$)

Comment: The solutions may not be convex functions, but that is different from saying that the set of solutions is convex.

Comment: I will edit the question, then

Comment: @Rodrigo I guess this is what the question meant.

Comment: You can prove that the set of solutions is convex without solving the system. The question of whether every solution is convex is nontrivial and would probably require some numerics. I think it is fairly clear from the wording that the question is asking for the former, not the latter.

Comment: @MichaelLee I guess then that the set of solutions of any ODE is convex, since every linear combination of solutions is a solution. Is that correct?

Comment: No, only the sets of solutions for linear ODEs would be convex! Also, linear combinations of solutions to homogeneous linear ODEs are solutions themselves, but this is not true for nonhomogeneous linear ODEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions $y$ to any linear differential equation $L\,y=f$, where $L$ is a linear differential operator and $f$ is a source function, form a convex set of functions.  To show this, suppose $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions, and $k_1$ and $k_2$ are any scalars, then
$$L\,\left(k_1\,y_1+k_2\,y_2\right)=k_1\,\left(L\,y_1\right)+k_2\,\left(L\,y_2\right)=k_1\,f+k_2\,f=\left(k_1+k_2\right)\,f$$
by linearity of $L$.  Now, if $k_1+k_2=1$, then we conclude that
$$L\,\left(k_1\,y_1+k_2\,y_2\right)=f\,,$$
whence $k_1\,y_1+k_2\,y_2$ is also a solution.  This shows that the solution set is therefore convex (in fact, affine, as remarked by Giuseppe Negro).  Thus, all you have to check is whether your differential operator $L$ is linear, and in your problem, $L$ is indeed linear.  More generally, the solution set of any linear equation (not necessarily a differential equation) is an affine (whence convex) set.

Comment: And this shows that the solution set is affine, which is stronger than convex. (Just a tiny remark)